# OpenGL : glLookAt : Sidestepping

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

In my game, you can move forward and backwards but I don't know how to side step to the left or right

```
GLfloat v[] = {[self centerAtIndex:0] - [self eyeAtIndex:0],[self centerAtIndex:1] - [self eyeAtIndex:1], [self centerAtIndex:2] - [self eyeAtIndex:2]}; 

//forward
[self setEye:[self eyeAtIndex:0] + v[0] * SPEED_MOVE atIndex:0];
[self setEye:[self eyeAtIndex:2] + v[2] * SPEED_MOVE atIndex:2];
[self setCenter: [self centerAtIndex:0] + v[0] * SPEED_MOVE atIndex:0];
[self setCenter: [self centerAtIndex:2] + v[2] * SPEED_MOVE atIndex:2];

gluLookAt(eye[0], eye[1], eye[2],center[0],  center[1], center[2], 0.0, 1, 0.0);
```

Can anyone give me the **actual code** to make the camera go sideways.  I have tried switching the v[2] and v[0] and that does make me move sideways for a couple of angles only, it seems to go the opposite way most the time or even forward.

**Solution**

```
float up[3] = {0, 1, 0};
        float forward[3] = { center[0] - eye[0],center[1] - eye[1],center[2] - eye[2] };

        float left[3];
        left[0] = forward[1] * up[2] - forward[2] * up[1];
        left[1] = forward[2] * up[0] - forward[0] * up[2];
        left[2] = forward[0] * up[1] - forward[1] * up[0];

        // now translate your eye position
        [self setEye:[self eyeAtIndex:0] - left[0] * SPEED_MOVE atIndex:0];
        [self setEye:[self eyeAtIndex:2] - left[2] * SPEED_MOVE atIndex:2];
        [self setCenter: [self centerAtIndex:0] - left[0] * SPEED_MOVE atIndex:0];
        [self setCenter: [self centerAtIndex:2] - left[2] * SPEED_MOVE atIndex:2];  


        if (([self eyeAtIndex:2] >= MapSizeZ || [self eyeAtIndex:0] >= MapSizeX  || [self eyeAtIndex:2] <= 1 || [self eyeAtIndex:0] <= 1) || [self checkCollisionWithPoint:CGPointMake([self eyeAtIndex:0] ,[self eyeAtIndex:2])] ){

            [self setEye:[self eyeAtIndex:0] + left[0] * SPEED_MOVE atIndex:0];
            [self setEye:[self eyeAtIndex:2] + left[2] * SPEED_MOVE atIndex:2];
            [self setCenter: [self centerAtIndex:0] + left[0] * SPEED_MOVE atIndex:0];
            [self setCenter: [self centerAtIndex:2] + left[2] * SPEED_MOVE atIndex:2];  
        }
```

Comment: "with all that experience, could you answer my question please :)" You have an answer; this one. The answers to your original question were good too. The reason I gave your question a -1 is because you want someone to write your code for you, rather than simply taking the perfectly valid answers you have been given. Implementing a vector cross product is not hard; indeed, any vector math library worth its salt will have one. From there, you should be able to transcribe the algorithm AndiDog gave you into code. There is no reason that valid answers must come in the form of source code.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, generally I completely agree with you. However this has just broken my brain for too long.  I had brought a 3D book on the subject but went completely over my head :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a vector pointing sideways by calculating the cross product of the up vector (here [0 1 0]) and the "look" vector (here `center - eye`). From that you get a vector pointing to the right or left side depending on the order. Then just add/subtract that vector to the current camera position (eye, center) in order to strafe.

Coding it yourself should be fairly easy, the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Coordinate_notation) is a simple formula. And there are many fully implemented camera classes available on the Internet.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "cross product" not "vector product".

Comment: @Nicol: Both terms are commonly used and fully interchangeable.

Comment: Could you post the code please?  I really would love you for it

Comment: @AndiDog: I managed to get through a college linear algebra class, a full year of graphics courses, and 10 years as a game developer without ever having heard of the "vector product". I just checked my old linear algebra textbook's index, and it doesn't have an entry for "vector product." But it does have one for "cross product". Admittedly, that's not a representative sampling, but I'd bet more people have heard the term "cross product" than know the term "vector product."

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, with all that experience, could you answer my question please :)  Its my final issue :(

Comment: @Nicol: Okay, "cross product" also won the Google battle. I'll edit.